# Getting Error too many indices for tensor of dimension 3

Tags: pytorch, faster-rcnn

I am trying to Read an Image using GeneralizedRCNN, Input shape is given as a comment with code. The problem is I am getting an error while tracing the model with input shape. The error is :

```
> trace = torch.jit.trace(model, input_batch) line Providing the error
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py:467:
> RuntimeWarning: Iterating over a tensor might cause the trace to be
> incorrect. Passing a tensor of different shape won't change the number
> of iterations executed (and might lead to errors or silently give
> incorrect results).   'incorrect results).', category=RuntimeWarning)
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-25-52ff7ef794de> in <module>()
>       1 #First attempt at tracing
> ----> 2 trace = torch.jit.trace(model, input_batch)
> 
> 7 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/detectron2/modeling/meta_arch/rcnn.py
> in <listcomp>(.0)
>     182         Normalize, pad and batch the input images.
>     183         """
> --> 184         images = [x["image"].to(self.device) for x in batched_inputs]
>     185         images = [(x - self.pixel_mean) / self.pixel_std for x in images]
>     186         images = ImageList.from_tensors(images, self.backbone.size_divisibility)
> 
> IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 3
```

```
model = build_model(cfg)
model.eval()
# print(model)
input_image = Image.open("model/xxx.jpg")
display(input_image)
to_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()
input_tensor = to_tensor(input_image)
# input_tensor.size = torch.Size([3, 519, 1038])
input_batch = input_tensor.unsqueeze(0)
# input_batch.size = torch.Size([1, 3, 519, 1038])
trace = torch.jit.trace(model, input_batch)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please be mindful when asking for help. You haven't said a word, nor given a clear description of the situation. Your post doesn't even contain a question! Do you really think someone will be able or want to help? You should start by giving the full error traceback as well as your model definition and the input shapes.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because `input_batch.size = torch.Size([1, 3, 519, 1038])`  has 4 dimensions and `trace = torch.jit.trace(model, input_batch)` expected to get a 3 dimensions as input.

you don't need `input_batch = input_tensor.unsqueeze(0)`. delete or comment this line.

Comment: Without unsqueeze I am getting 
torch.Size([3, 519, 1038]) shape for image_tensor, but while trace its again giving error too many indices for tensor of dimension 2.

Answer (score 0):

By default
..

The torch.jit.trace function cannot be used directly. However, it does provide a wrapper called that the model can take a tensor or a tuple of tensors as input. You can find a way to use it because of them.

The code for tracing the Mask RCNN model looks like this:

```
import torch
import torchvision
from detectron2.export.flatten import TracingAdapter
def inference_func(model, image):
    inputs= [{"image": image}]
    return model.inference(inputs, do_postprocess=False)[0]
print("cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS: ",cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS)   ## RETURNS : cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS:  drive/Detectron2/model_final.pth
model= build_model(cfg)
example= torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224)
wrapper= TracingAdapter(model, example, inference_func)
wrapper.eval()
traced_script_module= torch.jit.trace(wrapper, (example,))
traced_script_module.save("drive/Detectron2/model-final.pt")
```